# Accessing IBM IMM settings from Windows?

Tags: ibm

I have an IBM System x3400 M3 Server -[7379KKG], with Win2008R2 installed in a different country. Somehow the consult who helped me installing it missed the IMM settings, or for some reason I can not find it online in that LAN (The cable is plugged well).

I tried communicating with the IMM using   IBM Advanced Settings Utility, but every time I issue any commend, I get (IPMI command error, please check your IPMI driver and IBM mapping layer installation)

Is there anyway to fix the error above with IPMI? or if there is any tool that let me communicate with IMM from within Windows?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to make a telnet session to the IMM

Comment: The problem is that IMM is not reachable via the network, so I thought if I can get a tool the interacts internally with the IMM chip.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this post while trying to find an answer.
May be a bit late for Khamees, but hopefully it helps someone else out there.
After spending an hour trying to work out if I downloaded the correct version of ASU or BIOS patch. I finally realised I needed to elevate my privileges. Doh!
I'm an admin of the server, but due to windows UAC, you still need to run the command prompt as an Administrator.
Click START - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator.
Then all the commands work. Too easy.

Answer (score 1):

I went back and forth on this one on a 2008R2 server until I realized that I was not in the administrator command prompt. That solved everything. I could kick myself for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some information:

I found [this blog post](http://serverchronicle.blogspot.de/2012/08/configuring-ibm-imm-from-windows.html) that lead me to a solution:

To configure an IMM using the ASU tool you need this basic commands:

- asu64.exe set IMM.HostName1 `hostname`
- asu64.exe set IMM.HostIPAddress1 `address`
- asu64.exe set IMM.HostIPSubnet1 `netmask`
- asu64.exe set IMM.GatewayIPAddress1 `gateway`
- asu64.exe set IMM.DHCP1 disabled
- asu64.exe rebootimm

You can also run the tool in batch mode using the following command:

`asu64.exe batch <FILE>`

where `<FILE>` would contain the following lines following the example from above:

```
 set IMM.HostName1 <hostname>
 set IMM.HostIPAddress1 <address>
 set IMM.HostIPSubnet1 <netmask>
 set IMM.GatewayIPAddress1 <gateway>
 set IMM.DHCP1 disabled
 rebootimm
```